# Following previous instructions to set up adding ecw files to QGIS does not work

Tags: qgis, windows, ecw

I have followed the solutions to setting up ECW in QGIS.  However, none of them work.

In addition I get a mount - access denied error when trying to load the gdal-ecw and gdal-mrsid plug-ins using the OSGeo4W installer in advanced mode.  Any workarounds for this?

Comment: Running the installer as administrator should fix the "access denied" error.

Comment: How do you run the OSGeo4W installer as administrator?

Comment: Right-click "Run as Administrator". However, OSGeo4W has dropped ECW support. See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6838 and http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/osgeo4w-337-Rebuild-gdal-ecw-to-1-9-2-with-MSVC-2010-td5030143.html

Comment: You could try grabbing a gdal binary build from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk which still has ECW support (old v3.3) and copying libecwj2.dll to somewhere in your path and gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll to the gdal plugins dir.

Comment: have you tried http://www.faunalia.pt/node/438

Comment: You could run into some strange behaviour if you install gisinternals GDAL in C:\Program files\, as it may alter the PATH variable to its own location. I prefer to simply extract it to a separate directory, using the SDKShell.bat to start it.

Answer (score 2):

This was said to work (on the mailing list http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/RE-ECW-td4646269i20.html#a5040712):

1. from this archive (http://goo.gl/XiG21) copy gdal_ECW_JP2ECW into C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\1.9 directory.
2. copy all other dll of previous archive in C:\OSGeo4W\bin and C:\Windows\System32 directories

Comment: For those who have installed the standalone version, the dll should go into `C:\Program files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdalplugins\1.9`